# In D, how can I declare a hash of immutable types that is itself mutable?

Tags: d, immutability

I believe I was able to do this in an earlier version of the language, and indeed, code I wrote several months ago, which compiled fine then, does not compile now. Example:

```
immutable(X)[int] myhash;
myhash[5] = some_immutable_X; //previously fine.
myhash[5] = some_other_immutable_X; //previously fine also.
```

Now however, dmd complains with

```
Error: cannot modify immutable expression myhash[5]
```

I've experimented with some other possible syntax without success (e.g. (immutable X)[int]). It seems there is no longer a way to declare that the hash itself is mutable, but the contents are not? This seems like a fairly common use case: a data structure for storing references to things that ought not to be altered. Anyone have some insight into this?

Comment: Is X value or a reference type (i.e. class)?

Comment: Does not work with neither, but works well with 2.066.1 and before

Comment: X is a class (i.e. a reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it ever worked, it was a bug (probably due to the use of `void*` and incorrect casting somewhere in the AA implementation, since it hasn't been properly switched to templates yet AFAIK). You cannot mutate `immutable` values, and when you do

```
myHash[5] = value;
```

and the elements in `myHash` are `immutable`, then you are attempting to mutate an `immutable` value, even if it's the `init` value for that type (since an AA element gets initialized with the `init` value before it's assigned to, and the type system has no way of knowing whether the element was previously in the AA, so it can't treat the first assignment via `[]` as initialization and the others as assignment). If you want to have an AA of `immutable` elements, then you're going to need another level of indirection so that the elements themselves are not `immutable` but rather refer to something which is `immutable` - e.g by using a mutable pointer to an `immutable` type, or if you're dealing with classes, then use [`std.typecons.Rebindable`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#Rebindable) (since you can't have mutable class references to `const` or `immutable` objects).

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour did not work before 2.061, it has been work from 2.061 to 2.066.1. And it is "fix" in 2.067.

More info: [github pull](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/commit/2869ee9c1fb64f08b51d8d07ce72701dda4a6fae) and [bug issue](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13701)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to do it was to cast both the associative array and the element to mutable during insertion, like so:

```
cast()myhash[5] = cast()some_immutable_X;
```

I do something like this in my applications where I initialize immutable definitions loaded from external sources at runtime and then reference them in mutable entities, so I put a small generic example here: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/3a4233e5ec82